# Excel VBA - Strange Problem with Large Numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following test code:

```
Sub TestLoop()
    Dim LowC As Currency, HighC As Currency, x As Currency, y As Integer
    Const StepValue = 1000
    LowC = 1573869207000#
    HighC = 1573870107000#
    For x = LowC To HighC Step StepValue
        y = y + 1
    Next x
    MsgBox (1 + ((HighC - LowC) / StepValue) & "  ,  " & y)
End Sub
```

In Excel 2016, this produces the "wrong" answer - (901, 514). However, if I remove the first digit (1) from LowC and HighC so that they are respectively 573869207000 and 573870107000, I get the "right" answer - (901, 901). In Excel 2013, however, I get the "right" answer both times.

Does anyone have any idea why this is so? Have I hit some upper limit which is present in Excel 2016 but not in Excel 2013?

Comment: Overflowing a numeric type isn't something you *wonder* whether it's happened: you'd be getting a very loud & clear "Overflow" error (run-time error 6) if that were the case... `y` should be a `Long` though, since `HighC-LowC` (900K) is WELL outside the range of `Integer`... and that *should* be blowing up. Did you remove `On Error Resume Next` before posting by any chance? Note that because of the `As Currency` specifiers, the `#` type hints are superfluous and should be removed.

Comment: Still weird, at the end of the loop x = 1572869721000 which is less than highc = 1573870107000. There might be a hidden conversion to Double in the For loop.

Comment: No, I didn't remove any error traps. It is exactly how I have it in a VBA Module. Since first posting, I've discovered that I only get the "wrong" answer in Excel 2016. Excel 2013 works fine.

Comment: Did some testing, and I agree with @VincentG. If `x` is changed to `double` from the start, the problem disappears.

Comment: Yes, that seems to work. Any ideas why this is so?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon the # is set automatically by the VBE for long number. In fact the symbol for Currency is @, not # (symbol for Double type)

Comment: @VincentG ah, yes. <s>I should probably use type hints more often.</s> Still, they apply to the literal values, not the actual variables (which have a proper declared type), so there's an implicit conversion going on during the assignment. Could change to `LowC = CCur(....#)` for explicitness, but I don't think that would fix anything.

Comment: Interesting, can repro on Excel 2016. Weirdly too, if you change the loop to `For x = HighC To LowC Step -StepValue` the output is correct.

Comment: @BigBen the loop is just an inefficient way to get `x` to be `(HighC - LowC)/StepValue + 1`

Comment: I agree, it just doesn't make sense that I could reverse the step logic and get the right answer, while not get it with the current logic. That said, I would never loop with `Currency` to begin with.

Comment: So the question becomes, why would this loop exit after 513 iterations instead of 900. And yeah, the answer very likely has everything to do with floating-point rounding errors introduced by doing math with `Currency`.

Comment: @BigBen did you repro on a 32-bit Excel host? Mine is 64-bit... I suspect a 32-bit machine might be doing the math differently here. @ OP - please confirm bitness of both your Excel 2013 and 2016 installs.

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon Yes, 32-bit. I suspected this might be the issue, but didn't have 64-bit to compare.

Comment: I don't have Excel 2016 available to test at this time, but, from looking at the code, I suspect the problem lies with the constant `StepValue`. I would try explicitly specifying its type (with `Const StepValue As Currency = 1000`). If that resolves the issue, the problem is with how Excel 2016 is adding high currency values and integer values during the `For` loop. I will try to test this myself the next time I am on a machine with Excel 2016.

Comment: @NoahBridge no dice, already tried that. I think the bitness of the Excel install is the culprit here.

Comment: @BigBen - I think that you're onto something there. My Excel 2016 installation is 32bit whereas my Excel 2013 installation is 64bit. The 64bit version works fine.

Comment: This problem has caused me to wonder how to proceed and and I didn't know whether I could ask a further question here in the comments about data types or start a new question. In the end, I asked a new question [Q.59301051](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59301051/excel-vba-how-best-to-deal-with-large-whole-numbers) and I hope that someone may be able to help.