# How Best to Deal with Large Whole Numbers?

Tags: excel, vba

With reference to the [problem with 32bit Excel and large currency values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59290029/excel-vba-strange-problem-with-large-numbers), what is the preferred variable type to use with large, whole numbers in Excel VBA?

I am dealing with milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970, hence there are large, whole numbers such as 1573869207000. There are no decimals involved but they are too big to be LONG variables. I was initially advised to set them as CURRENCY type variables but as I need to use For/Next loops in the code using these variables, this can fail in Excel 32bit as seen in the link. Any ideas on what variable type is best to use - DOUBLE, DECIMAL etc. or just set them as VARIANT?

Comment: Reading [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary) I would say you could use `Decimal` type.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what practical application is there to measure long durations of time in milliseconds?

Comment: I'm dealing with data which has an associated timestamp. The timestamp includes the date and time and it can be historic, e.g. 2006:01:22:12:28:55.662. It can also be unsorted and so converting it to milliseconds helps to sort it in time order.

Comment: That value is well within the range of the Double Data type. So that would probably be the most efficient.  You could use the Decimal data type, but that might be overkill for what you need.  (Both give correct results for your previously posted problem).

Comment: @Ron - yes I thought of that type but for now, I've set them all as Variants and it seems to work OK. I tend to get a bit nervous about the precision of floating point numbers but I believe that the problem with them is at the decimal level rather than the whole number level ([see Not Exact](https://www.vitoshacademy.com/excel-vba-floating-point-numbers-in-excel-not-exact/)) and so in my case, using Double would probably be fine.

Comment: In general, you are better off using strong data types (explicitly declaring them).  Using `Variant` will occupy more memory, and also cause your application to run more slowly. That may or may not make a difference, depending on the complexity of your application.  For example, a `Double` requires 8 bytes; a `Variant` containing a number requires 16 bytes.  And you also have additional overhead for the Variant data type deciding what type of data it is receiving (eg Long, Integer, Double), and converting when it thinks it should.  You'll have the same issues with rounding no matter what.

Comment: @Ron - sound advice. I've now replaced all of the Currency declarations in my code with Double declarations and it works fine. Many thanks for this.